# Trying to understand JS prototypal inheritance, why won't this fire off?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the source code of backbone today to try and learn how it works. I tried to make my own initialize method that fires when a myModel is instantiated, but it doesn't seem to work. (alerts "default hello")

I was thinking that when myModel was created, it would copy the "this.initialize.apply" into myModel, and it would inherit the initialize method from Model's prototype. If myMethod didn't have an initialize method, it would look up the chain, but if myMethod does have it, it would use that instead. From what i'm (wrongly) thinking, myModel reads the apply like "myModel.initialize.appy(this, arguments)", but it seems to be calling Models instead.

Any idea's on where i'm going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/LvjpK/

```
function Model () {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
}


Model.prototype.initialize = function () {
    alert("Default Hello");
};


myModel = {
    initialize: function() {
        alert("Hello from myModel");
    }
};

var myModel = new Model();
```

Comment: All you're doing is overwriting the object you created and assigned to `myModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your `new Model()` line, you're creating a totally new object and putting a reference to it into the `myModel` variable.

The `initialize` function that you've defined on `myModel` earlier has absolutely no relevance. It never gets into play. It just gets picked up by the garbage collector as soon as you lose a reference to it by overwriting the `myModel` variable with it's new value.

Comment: Oooh that makes a lot of sense now, I can't believe I missed that! Looking into the sourcecode of Backbone again, the extend method must be copying the methods (including initialize) over to the new one. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be more along the lines of what you're going for:

```
function Model () {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
}


Model.prototype.initialize = function () {
    alert("Default Hello");
};


function MyModel() {
    // Call the Model constructor function.
    Model.apply(this, arguments);
}

// Make MyModel inherit from Model
MyModel.prototype = Object.create(Model.prototype);

// Override the initialize method on MyModel
MyModel.prototype.initialize = function() {
    alert("Hello from myModel");
};

var myModel = new MyModel();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uh2ev/